# Why is this Django view failing to run a Powershell script via subprocess.call?

Tags: python, django, powershell

The following **tests.py** works correctly and executes a Powershell script via *subprocess.call*:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", ". \"./testers.ps1\";", "&Foo(10)"])
```

Trying to execute the same call from within a Django/REST view, fails to do so:

```
import subprocess

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['POST'])
def bar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subprocess.call([f"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", ". \"./testers.ps1\";", "&Foo({request.data})"])

        return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(request.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Error:

```
[09/Jul/2021 08:31:52] "POST /profile-eraser/ HTTP/1.1" 201 5646
. : The term './testers.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ . "./testers.ps1"; &Foo({request.data})
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./testers.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

& : The term 'Foo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:21
+ . "./testers.ps1"; &Foo({request.data})
+                     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (hello:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

PS Script:

```
Function Foo($intIN)
{
    Write-Host ($intIN + 1)
}

Write-Host "PowerShell sample says hello."
```

Why am I able to run it from tests.py, but not from within a Django view?
What is the best way for me to execute this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django and very little knowledge on Python but I may be able to point in the right direction on what both errors mean. So, the first one, will probably be solved by using the absolute path of the script. The second one will probably be solved by [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.1#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) your ps1 script, so it loads the `Foo` function in memory.

Comment: For the second error, instead of using the call `&` just use `Foo -intIN request.data` (once the function is loaded, this is done by dot sourcing the script). I'm not sure if `({ })` is needed for variable expansion there.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the first error. Indeed passing the absolute path resolved it. In terms of the second issue, I forgot to indicate that I will be using f-string notation in Python, therefore it did not recognize the value of request.data. I will make this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Santiago Squarzon pointed out, I had to pass the absolute path to the script file. In terms of the second error, I forgot to indicate that an f-string for the last value of the subprocess.call

The working code now looks like so:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def bar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subprocess.call([f"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", ". \"C:\\Users\\me\\./testers.ps1\";", f"&hello({request.data})"])

        return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(request.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Check out my _non answer_, it may simplify things a bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant as an answer but to show you why a function *may not* be needed in this case.

If your PS Script looks like this, you wouldn't need to dot source it first to load the function and then call the function:

```
param(
    [parameter(mandatory)]
    [int]$intIN
)

Write-Host ($intIN + 1)
Write-Host "PowerShell sample says hello."
```

You could call it like this, which would simplify things a bit *maybe*:

```
& 'absolute\path\to\script.ps1' -intIN 123
```